# Python: modifying a value in one dictionary changes another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, chess

I'm making a chess program on Python by using dictionaries, and to set up my board I do:

```
EmptyBoard = {
    8:['☐','☒','☐','☒','☐','☒','☐','☒'],
    7:['☒','☐','☒','☐','☒','☐','☒','☐'],
    6:['☐','☒','☐','☒','☐','☒','☐','☒'],
    5:['☒','☐','☒','☐','☒','☐','☒','☐'],
    4:['☐','☒','☐','☒','☐','☒','☐','☒'],
    3:['☒','☐','☒','☐','☒','☐','☒','☐'],
    2:['☐','☒','☐','☒','☐','☒','☐','☒'],
    1:['☒','☐','☒','☐','☒','☐','☒','☐'],
    ' ':['⒜','⒝','⒞','⒟','⒠','⒡','⒢','⒣']
    }   #regular letters aren't wide enough

Default = {
    8:['♜','♞','♝','♛','♚','♝','♞','♜'],
    7:['♟','♟','♟','♟','♟','♟','♟','♟'],
    2:['♙','♙','♙','♙','♙','♙','♙','♙'],
    1:['♖','♘','♗','♕','♔','♗','♘','♖']
    }

Board = {}

def NewGame():
    Board.update(EmptyBoard)
    Board.update(Default)
    # some more code

NewGame()
```

this is fine until I have to edit a block in `Board` like so:

```
Board[3][2] = "X"
print(EmptyBoard[3][2]) # ==> Results in 'X', should stay '☐' or '☒'
```

this changes both `Board[x][y]` and whichever one of `EmptyBoard` and `Default` that `[x][y]` happens to be in.

This clones the pieces for every move after their first.

How do I make it so that only `Board` is edited?

Comment: Where and how is 'Board' defined? It would be great if you could provide a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Roy2012 edited the post, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Do you call "newGame" anywhere in the code? it would be great if you could provide a few lines of code that produce the 'wrong' results.

Comment: @Roy2012 I just call it, I only have this mode done anyways. Post has been edited to reflect this.

Comment: what does `Piece` containing? and post the complete code where you updating the board

Comment: @komatiraju032 unicode chess piece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Default` and `EmptyBoard` are dictionaries from something to list. When you call `update` in `NewGame`, you set `Board[3]` (for example) to refer to the exact same list as `EmptyBoard[3]`. Then, if you write something like:

```
Board[3][4] = X
```

you change that list - which is shared between `Board` and `EmptyBord` (or `Board` and `Default`).

To fix it, use `deepcopy`:

```
import copy

def NewGame():
    Board.update(copy.deepcopy(EmptyBoard))
    Board.update(copy.deepcopy(Default))
    ...
```

One more thing - the convention is to start variables in python with a small letter.